# Как перенести проект на Laravel на хостинг?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня такая структура сайта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне перенести мой проект на хостинг?
При этом в **Open Server'е** установил ***папку public*** папкой домена. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если корневая папка для файлов сайта отличается от папки www(public_html) (обычно файлы проекта на Laravel находятся в папке public), в таком случае нужно прописать следующую конструкция в файл .htaccess.

```html
# public_html/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Также нужно создать файл .htaccess в папке public и прописать в него директивы

```html
# public_html/public/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Первая картинка - структура вашего сервера, а не конкретно сайта.
Ваш сайт находится будет в public_html. Именно в public_html необходимо поместить содержимое laravel.loc (C:\OpenServer\domains\laravel.loc)

Comment: Да-да, я неверно выразился. Ну а если к файлам может быть прямой доступ, то это не грозит безопасности? Например, если не будет работать `.htaccess`?