# Редирект url в подпапку

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, nginx

Задача в следующем:

Нужно чтобы при переходе на site.com, подгружался index.php из папки subdir, которая находится в корне. При этом сайт не должен быть доступен по адресу site.com/subdir/.

Вопрос:

Возможно ли сделать подобное через .htaccess, или виртуальные хосты? В данный момент используется связка Apache+Nginx.

Comment: Просто заменить этот самый корень в настройках этого самого апача?

Comment: @ andreymal, Да я забыл добавить что там ещё есть подпапки а, они должны быть доступны.

Comment: вы хотите чтобы другие папки в корне были доступны по урл например site.com/images/ но при этом чтобы сайт грузился не из корневой папки а из одной этих подпапок? а смысл? для чего нужно такое решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу на свой вопрос сам.

Моё решение:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+subdir/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

в `/index.php` написать

```
$require = true;
require("subdir/index.php");
```

а в начале файла `/subdir/index.php` написать

```
if(!$require)header("Location: /");
```

подойдёт?

Comment: К сожалению нет...

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ name_of_dir/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Там, где name_of_dir вставляете имя

(В файле .htaccess)

Comment: Такой вариант не сработает! И что такое !^public?

Comment: У меня работает, может настройки сервера у вас какие-то неправильные?

Comment: В ответе на этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/695077/Как-перенести-проект-на-laravel-на-хостинг  рассказывают как сделать это.

Comment: Если и это не сработает, просто создавайте файл index.php (или любой другой), в котором подключайте нужные файлы из поддериктории.